# What is the most efficient way to add 3 characters at a time to an araylist from a text file?

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

Say you have a text file with "abcdefghijklmnop" and you have to add 3 characters at a time to an array list of type string. So the first cell of the array list would have "abc", the second would have "def" and so on until all the characters are inputted.

```
 public ArrayList<String> returnArray()throws FileNotFoundException
 {
    int i = 0
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scanCharacters = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanCharacters.hasNext())
    {
        list.add(scanCharacters.next().substring(i,i+3);
        i+= 3;
    }

    scanCharacters.close();

    return characters;
}
```

Comment: apart from bounds checking, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: what is `characters`

Comment: first off scanner is not the appropriate choice here.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, why do you think scanner is not appropriate for reading from a file? And also he can easily get what he wants by using the appropriate delimiter with the scanner...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<String> returnArray()throws FileNotFoundException
     {
        private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Scanner scanCharacters = new Scanner(file);
        String temp = "";

        while (scanCharacters.hasNext())
        {
            temp+=scanCharacters.next();
        }

        while(temp.length() > 2){
               list.add(temp.substring(0,3));
               temp = temp.substring(3);
            }
            if(temp.length()>0){
            list.add(temp);
            }



        scanCharacters.close();

        return list;
    }
```

In this example I read in all of the data from the file, and then parse it in groups of three. Scanner can never backtrack so using next will leave out some of the data the way you're using it. You are going to get groups of words (which are separated by spaces, Java's default delimiter) and then sub-stringing the first 3 letters off.
IE:
ALEXCY WOWZAMAN
Would give you:
ALE and WOW

The way my example works is it gets all of the letters in one string and continuously sub strings off letters of three until there are no more, and finally, it adds the remainders. Like the others have said, it would be good to read up on a different data parser such as BufferedReader. In addition, I suggest you research substrings and Scanner if you want to continue to use your current method.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If there's anything I'm missing do tell.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    Scanner scanCharacters = new Scanner(file);
    scanCharacters.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    String finalString = "";
    while (scanCharacters.hasNext()) {
        String[] tokens = scanCharacters.next().split("\t");
        for (String str : tokens) {
            finalString = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(str);
            for (i = 0; i < finalString.length(); i = i + 3) {
                x = i + 3;
                if (x < finalString.length()) {
                    list.add(finalString.substring(i, i + 3));
                } else {
                    list.add(finalString.substring(i, finalString.length()));
                }
            }
        }


    }


    System.out.println("list" + list);
```

Here i have used StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(str) of Apache String Utils to delete the blank space from the file tokens.and the if condition inside for loop to check the substring for three char is available in the string if its not then whatever character are left it will go to the list.My text file contains the below strings
**asdfcshgfser ajsnsdxs** in first line and in second line
**sasdsd fghfdgfd**

after executing the program result are as,

**list[asd, fcs, hgf, ser, ajs, nsd, xs, sas, dsd, fgh, fdg, fd]**